# Burn the [self-closing] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just saw a question using the [self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-closing) tag. It has no Wiki, and from what I can glean is used varyingly to refer to either aspects of XML/HTML tags or a graphical element that closes itself, for the most part. I looked through questions tagged with this manually (Apologies; I'm not sure if there's a querying system I could use.) and didn't see any questions where this was the only this tag. There are only 35 questions with this tag, and it has 1 follower.

This tag doesn't seem to add any value, as it's ambiguous. I propose burnination.

(Someone tell me if I'm doing this right. I did read the rules, but for some reason, I'm not at all confident.)

Comment: You are pretty much doing it right. I agree btw; the tag seems to have no real value.

Comment: I read the title thinking you wanted to request disallowing people to close vote their own questions. I was thinking that would have been a ridiculously pointless request.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I went over those 35 questions with that tag and removed, retagged, edited and/or close voted, whatever was needed.

The tag is now clear of questions and will be removed by the clean-up script that runs at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: Unless I add another question using it :P